# Find the shortest path with maximum gain

Tags: java, algorithm

[Problem link](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2929486/dashboard#s=p3) How can i modify my code so it give me shortest path with maximum weight.
Problem overview: I am giving a matrix and i have to go from one index to other with minimum index each index is having some gain , so i have to find the shortest path(if more than one shortest path are possible so path with maximum gain)
My code:

```
public static int min(int x , int y ,int endx,int endy,int n ,int m,int[][] p){
     int[] dirx ={1,-1,0,0 };
        int[] diry={0,0,1,-1};
        LinkedList<Point> som = new LinkedList<Point>();
        som.add(new Point(x,y));
       //dp[x][y]=p[x][y];

        while(!som.isEmpty()){
          Point xx = som.pop();
          for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

              int x1 =  xx.x + dirx[i];
              int y1  = xx.y + diry[i];

              if(x1>=0 && x1<n && y1>=0 && y1<m && p[x1][y1]!=-1 && dp[x1][y1]==-1){

                  dp[x1][y1] =  dp[xx.x][xx.y]+ 1;
                  som.add(new Point(x1,y1));

              }
          }

        }

    return dp[endx][endy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code add

```
((dp[x1][y1]==-1) || ((dp[x1][y1] == dp[xx.x][xx.y] + 1) && (w[xx.x][xx.y]+p[x1][y1] > w[x1][y1])))
```

instead of

```
(dp[x1][y1]==-1)
```

and inside the condition

```
w[x1][y1] = w[xx.x][xx.y] + p[x1][y1];
```

which means you will update the path result if you found better way of the same length

also you may optimize not to add same point several times, but i think this is not necessary in this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using Dijkstra's algorithm. But we need to compare both distance and gain amount instead of just distance in the original algorithm.

These are some code hints from me, so you only need to change some part of your code.

```
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
    int x,y, dist, gain;
    //Constructor is omitted.
    public int compareTo(Entry o){
        if(dist != o.dist)//Compare distance first
           return dist - o.dist;   
        return o.gain - gain;//Compare gain value
    }
}

//Method signature is omitted
PriorityQueue<Entry> q = new PriorityQueue();
q.add(new Entry(0,0,0,gain[0][0]);
int[][][]dist = new int[n][m][2];//Assume size of matrix is n x m
//Init dist array omitted
dist[0][0][0] = 0;//Init distance
dist[0][0][1] = gain[0][0];//Init gain amount, assume we have a gain matrix
while(!q.isEmpty()){
  Entry e = q.poll();
  if(dist[e.x][e.y][0] == e.dist && dist[e.x][e.y][1] == e.gain){
         for(all valid next positions (a,b))
            if(dist[a][b][0] > e.dist + 1 || (dist[a][b][0] == e.dist + 1 && dist[a][b][1] < e.gain + gain[a][b]){
               //Notice the condition to update the dist array
               dist[a][b][0] = e.dist + 1;
               dist[a][b][1] = e.gain + gain[a][b];
               q.add(new Entry(a,b,e.dist + 1, e.gain + gain[a][b]);
            }
  }
}
return dist[n-1][m-1][1];
```